# What is keeping me on 'Preparing your desktop...' after my Windows 7 parition migration?

Tags: windows-7, mbr, user-profiles, gparted, ubuntu-12.10

Here's the situation:

I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual booting on one 120gb ssd.

I recently purchased a 240gb ssd and wanted to migrate both of those partitions to this new one.

I used Gparted in Ubuntu to do most of the work, making sure to update GRUB.

Before I got rid of my old partitions, I could reach my new Windows 7 partition (F:) via GRUB > Windows dual boot screen> select the newer partition, and then I was on my F: drive.

So "great", I thought, "I can reach my new partitions, now I can clean out the old drive". After doing that, and updating GRUB, I now get hung up on "Preparing your desktop..." for about 2 minutes and come to a completely blank desktop. I've only been able to open Task Manager via Ctrl+Shift+Esc so far, or Ctrl+Alt+Del

My best guess is after the migration, my new settings didn't get changed over to point to my user profiles on my new partition, and were still pointing to my old one. Maybe it's BCDedit file getting confused.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I can access the entire drive via Ubuntu (I'm on a stick drive right now), but when I go to boot from it, I'm running into the aforementioned problems.

Does anyone know what I should be looking at or how to fix this?

Thank you

Edit: I tried GKoe's suggestion to no avail. I'm still loading to a blank desktop.

`/FixBoot` didn't seem to do anything.

`/RebuildBcd` and `/ScanOs` could not find any Windows installations.

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck on "Preparing your desktop" because windows is looking for a drive letter that it used to have, but since the migration, no longer exists or is changed.  Booting to a windows recovery disk and running fixboot will get you back into windows 7, but I do not know what effect it will have on GRUB and ubuntu.  If Grub is installed on your MBR, grub may be lost and need to be reinstalled.

Comment: Well GRUB gets overwritten every time I remake the MBR. It goes back and forth. I want GRUB to be my bootloader, though. GRUB doesn't have a problem handling both partitions.

How do I get to a command line in my recovery disk? The only thing I have at this point is my installation disk.

Comment: You should be able to boot into windows 7 recovery environment by booting the install disk and choosing "repair my computer".  From there you should have a command prompt option.  You can also download a windows 7 recovery disk iso (recovery only, nothign installable) http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/08/download-windows-7-isos-to-reinstall-without-restoring-your-system/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help. Still loading to a blank desktop.